# I am having trouble with SharedPreferences between two activities

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an activity which saves some data using **sharedpreferences** as below :

```
public void birthDateSharedPreferences(int calculatedBirthYear, int calculatedBirthMonth, int calculatedBirthDay)
    {
      SharedPreferences birthDatePreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = birthDatePreferences.edit();
      editor.putInt("birthChosenDay",calculatedBirthDay);
      editor.putInt("birthChosenMonth",calculatedBirthMonth);
      editor.putInt("birthChosenYear",calculatedBirthYear);
      editor.commit();
      Toast.makeText(birthDate.this,"The date was saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Intent saved = new Intent(birthDate.this,MenuActivity.class);
      startActivity(saved);
      finish();
}
```

---

here is the second activity

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
                   int birthChosenDay = prefs.getInt("birthChosenDay", MODE_APPEND);
```

and I have another activity in which I want to *use the data I saved in the first activity* ,
I searched and tried some codes but nothing worked ! **so how could I use the data which was saved in the first activity into the second activity** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second activity you should get the default shared preferences (the one used while saving)..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int birthChosenDay = prefs.getInt("birthChosenDay", MODE_APPEND);
```

AS:

```
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Will provide an access to a preferences file that is global for the whole application package ; any activity can access the preferences (internaly, the xml file holding the preferences will be named `your.application.package_preferences.xml`).

```
getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Will provide preferences only for the contextInstance class: only instances of the context's class can access these preferences (said your package is still `your.application.package` and you're in `your.application.package.SecondActivity`, internaly the preferences file is `SecondActivity.xml`).

Comment: getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); will provide preferences only for your SecondActivity, while you have saved your variables in the global preferences

Comment: So if I am in activity two and I want to  access the data saved then I use  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
             int birthChosenYear = prefs.getInt("birthChosenYear", MODE_APPEND);

Comment: yep, exactly give it a try :)